# strtotime value for 12:00 am?

Tags: php, time, strtotime

I meet a little problem but I don't understand that. I have 2 time frame : 11:35 AM and 12:35 AM. In PHP, I use strtotime function to compare them (as well 12:35 AM > 11:35 AM), but its not. And after debug value of them, I see :

```
strtotime("11:35 AM") : 1467711300
strtotime("12:35 AM") : 1467671700
```

Why strotime value of (12:35 AM) < value of (11:35 AM). I don't understand that. If I remove AM, PM then return values seem be true. But I don't want to remove it. Anyone can explaine for me about this problem ? And solution to fix that ? Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking at it wrong. `12:35 AM` is just after midnight (which is `12:00 AM`) - it IS before `11:35 AM`, which is just before noon (which is `12:00 PM`). You're thinking `12:35 PM`.

If you don't provide `AM` or `PM`, PHP then uses 24-hour time: `11:35` `<` `12:35`.